# Android 7.0 Doze is it stop all notification?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-doze

I am trying to learn Android 7.0 but i see this  comment.

**"When a device is on battery power, and the screen has been off for a certain time, the device enters Doze and applies the first subset of restrictions: It shuts off app network access, and defers jobs and sync"**

I dont understand exactly. İf it stop network in Doze mode ,how can i get whatsapp or email push message. Is it also restrict all in this mode?

Thank you for comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 7.0 Doze mode does block network access and other services as you said but it lets apps that have "wakelock" enable them periodically.
read http://lifehacker.com/how-android-doze-works-and-how-to-tweak-it-to-save-you-1785921957 for more