# Push notification not working on Android 7.0 (FCM) with release-apk

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

My android app is live on the store and its push notification stopped working suddenly on > 7.0 android os.

Dependencies :

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'    
'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

Notification builder code :

NOTIFICATION MANAGER :

```
   public void createNotificationManager(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            String id = "projectname";
            // The user-visible name of the channel.
            CharSequence name = "projectname";
            // The user-visible description of the channel.
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(id, name, importance);
            // Configure the notification channel.
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        }else{
            notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }
```

NOTIFICATION BUILDER :

```
                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new
                        NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_transparent);
                } else {
                    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                }
                notificationBuilder
                        .setContentTitle("Projectname")
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(intent.getStringExtra("gcm.notification.body")))
                        .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("gcm.notification.body"))
                        .setAutoCancel(true).setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND).setSound(soundUri)
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);

createNotificationManager();
notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

In debug apk it is working i checked but with the production (release_apk) it is not showing notification.

Please help in this.

Comment: it is the issue of notification Chanel . you have to create notification Chanel to retrieve notifications

Comment: Jay Thummar , I have already created the notification Chanel for the Oreo (8.0) version.  But for 7.0  it is not needed right. also in the debug build it is working fine.   Still it could be the issue ?

Comment: share your notification  builder code and service that you have written.

Comment: @war_Hero i shared my code please check.  I think it some other issues may be my FCM depedencies version ?

Comment: @ParvindraSingh maybe, check my answer and if you want give us grandle files too so i can test it more.

Comment: @ParvindraSingh check this answer too https://stackoverflow.com/a/42689313/6176003

Comment: @ParvindraSingh the issue is because you have not passed the channel in the notification builder

Comment: @war_Hero  this code is working in the debug build , not working in the release build.  I think it is not code issue. Still it might be ?

Comment: @war_hero your solution is worked for me .

Comment: @ParvindraSingh Sure, glad i could help let me post this as an answer to help others

Comment: hey i have posted an answer, if you could accept it then it would be great, as it will help anyone who face similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code it is evident that the `NotificationChannel` that you have **created is not passed** into the `NotificationCompat.Builder` hence you are facing this issue, you can read about it from the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels). [Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NotificationChannels) is an example of the notification given by google. If you want to read more about this refer the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications).

Comment: Hi war_hero , i have another problem that if app is killed state then notifcation not recieving in android 8.0 (Oreo)

Comment: oh, 1)in onMessageReceived have you put any condition checking for login state. 2)are you deleting the device token by any chance

Comment: Yes, it is working fine in < 8.0 if app i killed , I have found that it is not possible to use FCM notifications if app is killed in 8.0 check the link : 
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/378

Comment: how i can share you the service code , you need full code ? or which part you need ?  I am still not find an solution for 8.0 android kill state notifications.

Comment: A big thanks @war_hero , Its really helped me a lot !! :-)

Comment: anytime @ParvindraSingh glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have added the SHA1 of your release certificate into the Project Settings/General page for your Firebase project.

For each app you can add multiple SHA1's and you should include both your debug and release certificates.

Comment: Hi CodeChimp , thanks for answer , it is working in  < 7.0  android devices .  also on 7.0 it was working before.  I am checking my firebase settings and let you know .   But still suddenly it could be stopped ?

Comment: i have added already SHA1 in firebase project .  I just checked.

Comment: it is not allowing me to add my SHA key, it is showing "Your operation was forbidden."

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'    
'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

With latest update (based on [this url](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

And make sure that you are using google play services in latest version too:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Comment: if i will update my dependencies then i need to update my notification builder code too right ?   It will not effect any lower version support right ? please suggest if possible.

Comment: @ParvindraSingh try after update dependencies a push notification and check if it works maybe doesnt need to update your code, and tell us what happend

Comment: No @paraskevas  still struggling ,  I have used the War_hero solution and send the channel also , but after create release build notification not working.  I will try some another solution.